# $\int_0^T e^{\alpha t} dt \le T$ if $\alpha < 0$?

Tags: calculus

Is it true that $$\int_0^T e^{\alpha t} dt \le T$$ if $\alpha < 0$?
That is, is $$\frac{e^{\alpha T}}{\alpha} - \frac{1}{\alpha} \le T$$ true?

Comment: for what stands $T$ here?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner $T$ is a positive real number.

Comment: Why not just evaluate the integral and see?

Comment: If $\alpha <0$ then the function you're integrating takes value 1 at $t=0$ and then decays for positive $t$.  The hint I'd give you is to think about what an integral represents graphically.  And think of "$T$" on the right hand side of the inequality as an area coming from a rectangle of height 1 and base $T$.  Does that help?

Comment: You should add that $T\ge0$ in your question otherwise the inequality isn't true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\alpha <0$, then $e^{\alpha t}<1$ for all $t>0$, now integrate both sides of the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

The curvilinear trapezium defined by the arc of curve and the $t$-axis, between $t=0$ and $t=T$ is contained in the rectangle with height $1$ and width $T$.

Answer (score 0):

I propose to look at [the picture](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+e%5E(-2+t)+for+0+%3C+t+%3C+2) and think about the integral does.